# php facebook share button displayed, but like button not displayed

Tags: html, facebook

I have a website where I have to add facebook share and like button. I'm using the following code (from developers.facebook.com) and the share button is displayed without any problem, but the like button is not displayed.

```
<!-- Load the Facebook SDK asynchronously -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script async defer crossorigin="anonymous" src="https://connect.facebook.net/ro_RO/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v16.0" nonce="Pwix8BSv"></script>
<ul class="social-icon">
    <li class="ftco-animate">
        <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.uaic.ro" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-size="small" data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
    </li>
    <li class="ftco-animate">
        <div class="fb-share-button" data-href="https://www.uaic.ro" data-layout="button_count" data-size="small"><a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fyourwebsite.com%2Fyourpage.php&amp;src=sdkpreparse" class="fb-xfbml-parse-ignore">Share</a></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I tried something:

-> I put the code in a simple html file (to check if it's not a problem from my css files)
-> I tried to regenerate de code of the buttons on developers.facebook.com
-> I tried the new variant (where share button is incorporated in like button, but in this case none of them was displayed)
-> I tried the variant in en_EN
-> and others

Nothing worked.

Comment: Are you within the European Union? In that case, have you taken note of the big, fat hint shown at the start of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/ ...?